# How to make SEVERAL types BOTH serializable and deserializable to/from JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I wan't to save and load dicts, some of fields of which are datetime-s and ndarray-s. How to make both of these types JSON serializeble and deserializeble, so I can use both `json.load` and `json.dump`? The code for serializer and deserializer I want to provide myself

For datetime it will be string in specified format (datetime.strftime in serializer and datetime.strptime in deserializer) and for ndarray it will be one-line list.

How to do that? In many examples I found the following shorcomings appear:

1) only serialization provided (I need deserialization too)

2) only one custom type  serialization was provided (I need two)

How to accomplish?

Comment: Use a custom encoder https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder and decoder https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder

Comment: Should I write these classes per type, or per many types?

Comment: You should be able to use one class, then call `isinstance()` multiple times

Comment: What if I want to have multiple classes?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that either, I suppose

Comment: But how to connect several classes to routine?

Comment: If you look at the examples on the page, notice the `cls` parameter... `json.dumps(2 + 1j, cls=ComplexEncoder)`. If you have multiple classes, then that implies you're serializing different things. I would suggest one class if dates and arrays are part of the same json body, but one class can be composed of many other classes

Comment: @cricket_007 for JSONEncoder it is said to override default, how to implement custom JSONDecoder? It's API looks completely different with no methods told to override...

Comment: All you have is a `decode` function. You need to manually know which fields from that JSON are to be converted into dates or numpy arrays. For example, prefix the fields with the encoder with `np_` and `date_`, then in the decoder first do `json.loads()` to read the input string, loop over that, then update those fields with their new values, and return the `dict`

Comment: Yes, I know I should infer the type. But I am not sure with API. For encoder it is clearly stated that `default` should be overriden: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder  But for decoder I don't see such statement. How do you know I need to override `decode`? It hase default values which are not imported by default (`_w=WHITESPACE.match`), which makes me think it is not intended to override...